# Python.Ожидание запроса

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, while

У меня есть основной цикл вида:

```
while True:
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
              if sms == '!':
                   mes('Бла бла бла ответ')
```

Он ловит новые сообщения которому приходят боту, всё миленько и работает, но появилась нужна более сложных команд, то есть пользователь пишет к примеру "настройки" бот ему пишет вроде `"1-включить аниме,2-включать аниме всегда,3-автоматически убивать анимешников"` пользователь отвечает и бот понимает, что цифра `2` это ответ на предыдущее сообщение, а не новая команда в основном цикле

Была идея реализовать через `time.sleep()` Вроде засыплять бота и после конца засыпки смотреть что ответил человек, но идея в корне бредовая

Я нырнул в многопоточность:

```
def quest():
  t2 = threading.Thread(target=quest)
  t2.start()  
  yt = 1
  while yt < 2:
     for event in longpoll.listen():
         if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
             if sms == 'подкоманда 1':
                 mes('ответ на подкоманду 1')
             if sms == 'конец настроек':
                 yt = yt +1
                 t2.join()
```

Был создан вот такой монстр, который создавал под.while, но тут появился проблема с его выходом.

Вот в итоге обращаюсь к каждому читающему с просьбой о помощи, очень нждаюсь в подсказке реализации данной идеи, `input` то тут не впишеь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чат-ботов удобно реализовывать на [конечных автоматах](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82).

Например:

```
from enum import Enum

# Допустимые состояния диалога
class State(Enum):
    INITIAL = 1
    SETTINGS = 2

# Допустимые настройки
class Anime(Enum):
    PLAY_ANIME = 1
    PLAY_ANIME_ALWAYS = 2
    AUTO_KILL_OTAKU = 3

# Текущее состояние
state = State.INITIAL

# Текущие настройки
settings = Anime.PLAY_ANIME

while True:
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            if state == State.INITIAL: # состояние INITIAL
                if sms == 'настройки':
                    state = State.SETTINGS # переходим в состояние SETTINGS
                    mes('1-включить аниме,2-включать аниме всегда,3-автоматически убивать анимешников')
                else:
                    mes('неверная команда')
            elif state == State.SETTINGS: # состояние SETTINGS
                if sms == '1':
                    settings = Anime.PLAY_ANIME
                    state == State.INITIAL # переходим в состояние INITIAL
                elif sms == '2':
                    settings = Anime.PLAY_ANIME_ALWAYS
                    state == State.INITIAL # переходим в состояние INITIAL
                elif sms == '3':
                    settings = Anime.AUTO_KILL_OTAKU
                    state == State.INITIAL # переходим в состояние INITIAL
                else:
                    mes('неверная команда')
```

Comment: Всегда думал какого серьёзным таким программистам со стажем сидеть у компа и переписывать "играть в аниме"

Огромное душевное спасибо)